# Proving a particular set in $[0,1]$ has measure 1

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I saw this question while looking through some real analysis PhD qualifier exams.

> Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0,1]$. Let $c$ be a positive constant such that for all $0\leq a,b\leq1$, we have $$m(E \cap [a,b]) \geq c(b-a).$$ Prove that $m(E)=1$.

My approach is to show that the complement $F := [0,1] \backslash E$ has measure zero. By countable additivity of the Lebesgue measure, we have
$$m(E \cap [a,b])+m(F \cap [a,b]) = b-a \implies (1-c)(b-a) \geq m(F\cap [a,b]).$$
Let $\{x_k\}$ enumerate the rational numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$, and for a fixed $\epsilon > 0$ and each $k$ we consider the interval $$I_k = [x_k - \frac{\epsilon}{(1-c)2^{k+1}}, x_k+\frac{\epsilon}{(1-c)2^{k+1}}].$$
Then
$$m(F) = m(F \cap [0,1]) = \sum ^\infty _{k=1} m(F \cap I_k)\leq (1-c)\sum _{k=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{(1-c)2^k} = \epsilon.$$
Here I made the assumption that the intervals $I_k$ would cover $[0,1]$, but I'm not sure if this is actually true.

**EDIT.** Okay the assumption is definitely not true, since the intervals are getting smaller and thus we cannot cover all irrational numbers in $[0,1]$. How do we work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $\delta >0.$ Let $D$ be a closed set with $D\subset E$ and $m(D)>m(E)-\delta.$ Let $V$ be a family of open intervals with $\bigcup V\supset D$ and $m([0,1]\cap (\,\bigcup V\,))<m(D)+\delta.$

Now $D$ is compact so there exists a finite $W\subset V$ with $\bigcup W\supset D.$  So $m([0,1]\cap (\,\bigcup W\,))\le m([0,1]\cap (\,\bigcup V\,))<m(D)+\delta\le m(E)+\delta.$

Let $T=[0,1]\setminus \bigcup W.$ Then $m(([0,1]\setminus D)\cap E)\ge m(T\cap E).$ But the complement in $[0,1]$ of a finite union of open intervals is the union of a finite set of pair-wise disjoint intervals (including degenerate 1-point intervals), so $m(T\cap E)\ge c\cdot m(T).$  Therefore $$m(E)=m(D)+m(([0,1]\setminus D)\cap E)\ge$$ $$\ge m(D)+m(T\cap E)\ge$$ $$\ge m(E)-\delta+c\cdot m(T)=$$ $$=m(E)-\delta+c(1-m([0,1]\cap (\,\bigcup W\,))\,)\ge$$ $$\ge m(E)-\delta+c(1-m(E)-\delta))$$ which simplifies to $$\delta\ge c(1-m(E)-\delta).$$ This is not possible for every $\delta>0$ unless $m(E)=1.$

Comment: I found a possible error after acceptance. I had $c(1-m(\cup W)\ge c(1-m(E)-\delta)$ which I am unsure of, so I modified the A to be sure

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, the union of open sets might not be contained in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @KelvinLian . Yes. I needed  an adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy consequence of [Lebesgue Density Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem).

If $m(E) <1$ then there would be points of $E^{c}$ at which $E$ has Lebesgue density  $0$ but the hypothesis implies that the Lebesgue density is at least $c$.

Answer (score 2):

Lebesgue differentiation theorem is powerful enough to give a neat and short proof. However, a proof using weaker result is also available:

For each partition $\Pi = \{ I_1, \ldots, I_n \}$ of $[0, 1]$ into non-overlapping subintervals $I_1, \ldots, I_n$, define the operator $T_{\Pi} : L^1[0,1] \to L^1[0, 1]$ by

$$ T_{\Pi} f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \biggl( \frac{1}{m(I_k)}\int_{I_k} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr) \mathbf{1}_{I_k}(x). $$

Let $\|\Pi\| = \max\{m(I_k) : k = 1, \ldots, n\}$ be the mesh size of $\Pi$. Then we have:

> **Lemma.** Let $(\Pi_n)$ be a sequence of partitions of $[0, 1]$ such that $\|\Pi_n\| \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Then for each $f \in L^1[0, 1]$,
> $$ T_{\Pi_n} f \to f \quad \text{in $L^1$ as $n\to\infty$}$$

So, if $(\Pi_n)$ is as in the lemma, then by passing to a subsequence if necessary, we find that $(T_{\Pi_n}\mathbf{1}_E)$ converges to $\mathbf{1}_E$ a.e. However, the assumption tells that $T_{\Pi_n}\mathbf{1}_E \geq c > 0$ everywhere. So by passing to the limit, $\mathbf{1}_E \geq c$ a.e. and hence $\mathbf{1}_E = 1$ a.e. Therefore $m(E) = 1$.

---

*Proof of Lemma.* We easily find that

$$ \| T_{\Pi} f\|_{L^1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \biggl| \int_{I_k} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr| \leq \|f\|_{L^1}. $$

Moreover, if $g$ is any continuous function on $[0, 1]$, and if $(\Pi_n)$ is a sequence of partitions on $[0, 1]$ such that the mesh size converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, then each $T_{\Pi_n}g$ is bounded by $\sup|g|$, and $T_{\Pi_n} g \to g$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$. So, for any $f \in L^1[0,1]$ and $g \in C[0,1]$, the dominated convergence theorem shows that

\begin{align*}
&\limsup_{n\to\infty} \| T_{\Pi_n} f - f \|_{L^1} \\
&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( \| T_{\Pi_n}(f-g) \|_{L^1} + \| T_{\Pi_n} g - g \|_{L^1} + \| f-g \|_{L^1} \right) \\
&\leq 2\| f-g \|_{L^1}.
\end{align*}

Since $C[0, 1]$ is a dense subspace of $L^1[0, 1]$ and $g \in C[0,1]$ is arbitrary, the above bound can be made arbitrarily small. Therefore the desired conclusion follows. $\square$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this argument standard?